# Lomonosov's three literary styles

Tags: история-языка, лексикон, стилистика

According to Serhii Plokhy's *Lost Kingdom*, at a time of linguistic-nationalist tension, Mikhail Lomonosov prescriptively defined three styles:

> the high style, to be used for the composition of epics, odes, and poems, was supposed to employ the vocabulary common to Church Slavonic and literary Russian; the intermediate style, to be used in dramatic works, was to rely on the vernacular but avoid colloquialisms; and the third, lower style, which admitted the language of townsfolk and peasants, was reserved for comedy.

The man is so famous that I can only imagine his plan had some influence. But to what degree did authors of the late 1700s follow these recommendations?

Comment: this is a huge topic, which is dealt with at length and under different angles by historians of literature, this monograph seems quite relevant (if you read Russian) [История русского литературного языка XI-XVIII вв. (Раздел III, Глава 4)](http://macedonia.kroraina.com/pfir/pfir_3_4.htm)

Comment: The expression "написать высоким штилем" still exist. Notice, how "style" is pronounced here in obsolete "sh-" way

Comment: this question can not have one sufficient and short enough answer.